# What is the group/party size in DC Universe Online?

Tags: dc-universe-online

I see that DCU Online is going to a free to play mode soon and I was wondering how large of a group can you play with in DCU Online?

I play PC games once a week with a group of about 5 people and we are looking for something new we can all play together online, and are looking into the superhero MMORPG's that are now becoming free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups you can create, can be at 4 players max.

Comment: That's a bummer.  Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2011, when this question was asked/answered, you would go into your quick menu and select "Form Raid" in order to add up to 8 people in a group.  That way, you were able to queue for 8-player content with a pre-formed party, or reap the benefits of team play in open-world content such as Bounties.

The game as it is currently, you can form a raid group without having to designate it as such.  Currently, you are only able to queue for content equal or greater than your party size.

Private chats are another story.  Those are not limited in size, nor are they limited to faction (the way pre-formed groups are, currently).

Comment: If possible, you might want to add when this change happened! The previous answer was correct for it's time, but adding more information as to the change over will help if anyone google's their way to this question!

Comment: @NBN-Alex the previous answer was not correct for its time; there has always been the ability to form an 8-person group.  The difference was that it wasn't intuitive before.  The original poster wanted to be able to play with their four other friends on a regular basis.  That has always been possible, and it's unfortunate that they were told "4 players max."

Comment: I see! The best I can do then is to upvote the better (and correct) answer here.